# How to assign key name in a single dimensional array

Tags: php

I'm trying to assign country code as key, country name as value. The following is my code, if any wrong please correct me.

```
$return = array();
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    array_splice($return, count($return),0, array($value['country_code']=>$value["name"]));
}
```

Comment: You are making it way too complicated: `$return[ $value['country_code'] ] = $value["name"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like this would suffice:

```
$return = array_column($result, 'name', 'country_code');
```

this is essentially a shorter version of

```
foreach($result as $key => $value){
    $return[$value['country_code'] ] = $value["name"];
}
```

Comment: isn't it `array_column($result, 'name', 'country_code');`

Comment: Thank you bro, I was figure out around a hour to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the $result to set the value.

```
foreach($result as $v)
{
  $return[$v['country_code']] = $v['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here one more approach using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) :

```
$modified = array_map(function($result){    
    return [$result['country_code'] => $result['name']];
}, $resultset);
```

Cheers!